# What is wrong with my ffmpeg command?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I use this command to try to transcode a video file (video h264 high 10 to h264 high and copy all the rest) but it keeps giving me the error `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'copy'
copy: Invalid argument`

The command I use is `ffmpeg -i $1 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -profile:high -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:t copy $2`

What is wrong with this command?

Comment: Try dropping the `-profile` option and use the `-f` option (e.g. `-f mp4`) after `-c:t copy` and just before `$2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command contains `-profile:high` which is parsed by FFmpeg as an option name. Thus, `-c:a` is parsed as its value. So, the next `copy`, now seen as unpaired, is treated as the output name. Since it has no extension, FFmpeg can't discern the output file format.

The correct syntax for profile is `-profile:v high`

So use

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -profile:v high -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:t copy $2
```

Comment: can you take a look at my question : https://superuser.com/questions/1283764/ffmpeg-zoompan-filter-duration-option-not-working